# Get html element out of component template in angular 4?

Tags: html, angular, dom

I want to get an element with css selector that is not within component template.
e.g:
I want to get an element with `[data-name="target"]` selector.
I used `ElementRef` in my component but it returns null unless the element was within component template.

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  private updateTarget() {
    if (this.targetSelector == '') return; // this.targetSelector => [data-name="target"]
    let element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(this.targetSelector); 
    // element is null
  }
```

Comment: Is the element part of a child component or something that is programatically added via structural directive? What are you trying to do with the element after you select it?

Comment: The element can be within all over the page, I don't know where is it, because it can be dynamically create by programmer, I want to fill it with some values. Actually I'm written a date-time picker, so I want to get an element selector to fill it with selected day.

Comment: Then you probably want `document.querySelector(this.targetSelector)`

Comment: No, I would not recommend interacting with the DOM at all for something like this. Angular has an API to do this. The best solution would be to write a service that does the needed functionality, include it in the module, and inject it into the child components.